# Como realizar Insercion multiple MSSQL+Node.js?

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

Estoy intentando de registrar múltiples datos en una BD SQL server, utilizando Node.js de la siguiente forma:

```
           for(var i = 0;i<cantidad;i++){
                var vuelta = i+1;
                records.push([respuesta,vuelta+'/'+cantidad,hoy,req.query["id_usuario"],req.query["descripcion"],req.query["proveedor"]]);
            console.log(records)
            }

            var cons = 'insert into registros (id_insumo,cantidad,fecha,id_usuario,observacion,lote_proveedor) values ?';
            var request2 = new sql.Request();
            console.log(req.query)
            request2.query(cons,[records] , function (err, rows) {
                if(!err){
                    res.send(rows['recordsets'][0]);
                    console.log(rows)
                } else{
                    res.send(err)
                }
            });
```

De esta forma es posible completar la lista de forma dinamica y luego entregarla en una unica consulta que inserte todo a la BD. Este metodo me funciona correctamente con MYSQL pero en SQL server me envia error.

Este es el error en concreto:

```
    node:6248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.
    at handleError (c:\AppInsumo\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:366:15)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on.token (c:\AppInsumo\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:827:12)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Parser.parser.on.token (c:\AppInsumo\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:37:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (c:\AppInsumo\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (c:\AppInsumo\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:279:11)
    at Parser.Readable.push (c:\AppInsumo\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:240:10)
    at Parser.Transform.push (c:\AppInsumo\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:139:32)
(node:6248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6248) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaya por delante que de Node.js yo se más o menos, nada de nada, pero viendo la construcción, yo diría, que en tú parámetro ? se inserta el array de datos, para la tabla. Supongo que eso será válido ya que antes de lanzar la query sustuirá ese interrogante por todos los valores separados por comas.
Pero en sql server la sintaxis de la insercción no es válida. Los values van entre paréntesis. De manera que puedes insertar varios registros con la misma insert, separando values (xxxx,xxx),(yyyy,yyy),(zzzz,zzz);

```
 var cons = 'insert into registros (id_insumo,cantidad,fecha,id_usuario,observacion,lote_proveedor) values (?)';
```

Comment: Aun implementando los paréntesis como me indicas (?) no me reconoce el signo de pregunta como el array de datos.  Incorrect syntax near '?'. Al momento de enviar a insertar, se envia la consulta con el signo de pregunta en vez de con los datos del array.

Comment: Entonces tu código en node, no es correcto, no se trata de como lo envía al Sql, porque simplemente no te hace el replace que planteas.

Comment: efectivamente, por lo mismo estaba consultando como se podía hacer en SQL server ya que en MYSQL funciona pero en MSSQL no. revisando la documentacion de MSSQL en node no existe una funcion que haga tal cosa. Por ende lo que hice fue generar un array con los datos e insertar este al final de la consulta. Tu respuesta me ha servido mucho ya que no sabia que se podian insertar varios registros como indicas: values (xxxx,xxx),(yyyy,yyy),(zzzz,zzz); de esta manera pude solucionarlo. Muchas gracias.